# storage location of whatsapp data in android sets

Tags: samsung-mobile, whatsapp

I am using samsung s3 mini hanset. I am a part of many whatsapp groups. Usually I am receiving many messages containing images and videos from these groups. When I open my whatsapp account these images and videos are automatically downloaded to my device memory and hence it becomes always hanged due insufficient memory space. I want to set the sd card as memory location for these whatsapp downloading data. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

From WhatsApp FAQ site:

> **How do I move WhatsApp to the microSD card?**
>
> Moving WhatsApp to your memory card (microSD card) is not possible at
> this time.
>
> We are working on improving our application size and memory
> utilization. There are technical hurdles that do not allow us to move
> our application to the microSD card. In the meantime, we recommend
> that you help make room for WhatsApp by moving as many other
> applications and media files as you can, to your microSD card.

Reference: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/21068307